# MongoDB / NodeJS can't push to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to add tags to existing tags in a MongoDB collection with this Schema:

```js
const workSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: "Tile can't be blank"
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  imageURL: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  workURL:{
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  tags:{
    type:Array
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }

});

const Work = mongoose.model('Work', workSchema);
module.exports = Work;
```

I made an API that makes a PUT request to "/api/work/:workId/tags"

```js
exports.updateTags = (req, res) =>{
  try{
    const newTags = req.body.tags.split(',');
    newTags.forEach(tag => {
      db.Work.update(
        {"_id": req.params.workId},
        {
          $push:{
            tags: tag
          }
        }
      )

    })
    res.status(200).send({message : "tags updated"})
  }
  catch(error){
    res.status(400).send(error)
  }

}
```

request.body:

```
{
  tags:"a,b,c"
}
```

The problem is that the array won't update with the new tag values

I searched for other ways to update in the docs and on the web but I didn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `_id` in your `workSchema` so the type of `_id` would be `ObjectId`

But `req.params.workId` is probably a `String`, so querying an `ObjectId` with a `String` won't work.

So you should convert `req.params.workId` to `ObjectId` using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

```js
{ "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.workId) }
```

But you can improve your code a bit more by using `.findByIdAndUpdate` and `$each` operator

- `.findByIdAndUpdate` will automatically convert your `_id` to `ObjectId`
- You can use `$each` to `$push` multiple array elements at the same time without using `.forEach`

```js
Work.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.workId, {
  $push: { "tags": { $each: newTags } }
})
```